# What happens if ExecutorService's queue is full

Tags: java, concurrency, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I have a big file up to terabytes, and my task is to process line by line. Each line should take 5s to accomplish. To improve the performance I dispatch the process to a fixed thread pool like this

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);     

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(line);
  executor.execute(worker); 
}
```

My question is what happens if I overwhelm the executor's queue by putting so many tasks. Does it throw `StackOverflow`?

Comment: 2 year back I was asked this question in interview :)

Comment: @Vipin: and you've got the job?

Comment: I could not answer this. After few similar questions I started going through JDK source code wherever possible. It helps to understand design better.

Answer (score 7):

This might be off topic a little bit but one option for this issue is using a fixed length Blocking Queue and  use ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunPolicy().  That way, if the consumer is not fast enough (thus the queue is filling up) then caller thread (producer) will be utilized to run the task itself.  We can initialize an Executor like following:

```
executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT,
        DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(DEFAULT_QUEUE_LENGTH),
        new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

[From the API:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html#ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy%28%29)
"A handler for rejected tasks that runs the rejected task directly in the calling thread of the execute method, unless the executor has been shut down, in which case the task is discarded."

Answer (score 6):

It will throw an OOM error (gc overhead) if you do not process faster than you put.  You cannot get a `StackOverflow` as the stack doesn't change much.

@StinePike asks a good question.  `RejectedExecutionException` happens if there are no more threads to process items off the queue and the queue is full.  In this case default implementation of `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);` will use an unbounded `LinkedBlockingQueue`.  Your our only restriction is memory.

Comment: wil it throw RejectedExecutionException ?

Comment: @StinePike only if the queue is fixed size, which IIRC it is an unbounded queue by default.

Answer (score 3):

As you check the Executors.newFiexedThreadPool implementation,

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

Tasks will be thrown into a LinkedBlockingQueue and wait for thread to execute. If there are too much tasks waiting, it may throw OutOfMemory instead of StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

You will get OutOfMemoryError because newFixedThreadPool uses a unbounded blocking queue. You can avoid that by instantiating a ThreadPoolExecutor with a bounded queue.

Comment: What is the difference between bounded and unbounded queue?

Comment: its about the capacity of the queue. If there is a limit to its capacity [LinkedBlockingQueue(int capacity)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue%28int%29) then the queue is bounded whereas [LinkedBlockingQueue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue%28%29) is unbounded.